# Dynamic styling on the image and its text using CSS 3

Tags: css

I have an background image for a menu bar as follows

[image: menu]

and it has four **constant** text displayed on each of the box. right most box is empty place. This image is made with all those static four vertical bars.

Now the problem is those four texts are so dynamic and are of variable lengths for different situation. Because of the variable lengths, its overlapping with those vertical bars when the texts not able to accommodate inside the box.
 What is the best option to deal with this scenario using styling or another way.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Case 1: Using Borders

You can give the links a `border-right` instead of relying on the image.

```
.nav li a {border-right: 2px solid #000;}
```

#### Case 2: Using Ellipsis

You can give a `text-ellipsis` for those links and make sure they come fit inside the lines:

```
.nav li a {max-width: 150px; text-ellipsis: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;} /* Get this thing right */
```

Comment: thanks for the reply and sorry for not adding one more information here. :( Actually that image and its vertical bar having some gradient effect so i cannot add a border-right to create the border effect.

Comment: @AlagesanPalani Then do one thing. Take the vertical bar, and instead of giving `border-right`, give as `background: url('') right center no-repeat`. This solves your issue! :)